# Laravel LDAP and Database connection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, active-directory

I have several different types of users who use my system. One set of users is unique as all their credentials are accessed via LDAP, the other users are all relatively similar but do have different roles. I am using the built in `User` class for the regular users (that is, not the ones who login using LDAP) and am using Laravel 4. I query the LDAP and it returns either *success* or *failure* but once I've done that I don't have a user logged in per se. I set up a "fake" user in the `Users` database, which I could then manually authorise by using it's `id`

```
Auth::loginUsingId($user_id);
```

In this case, when I have verified their details via LDAP I manually authorise them using the dummy account. In this sense, every user who logs in with LDAP credentials is authorised as this single dummy user. While this works it means making a redundant `User` with *false* information and it is just generally quite messy. Furthermore, I lose the rich information the LDAP provides.

Effectively, I'd like to be able to authorise a user when they are not actually a `User` according to the `Users` table. I believe the solution may lie in altering the `UserProviderInterface.php` or the `EloquentUserProvider.php`.